# Unable to connect a server through ssh

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a ubuntu machine from my mac
but I am getting

```
setsockopt SO_KEEPALIVE: Invalid argument
write: Broken pipe
```

as soon as I type in `ssh address`
and changing `ssh_config` including `TCPKeepAlive`, `ServerAliveInterval` do not fix my issue.

Does anyone know what might be happening?
Server is running on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that server and client are on different network

Therefore my machine was unable to find the target server machine of the given ip address.

(ya I know.. such failure should be more descriptive)

I hope this answer helps the other people experiencing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when the connection was dropped straight away (a firewall it seems).
Presumably it ends up calling setsockopt() on a socket that just closed.